# rsync multiple source and destination

Tags: bash, rsync

The following works as desired:

```
rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress /home/usr/test1/cool-beans /home/usr/test2/
rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress /home/usr/test1/pineapple /home/usr/test2/
rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress /home/usr/test1/pizza /home/usr/test2/
rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress /home/usr/test1/dragons /home/usr/test2/elephant/
```

However when I simplify it to this:

```
rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress \
    /home/usr/test1/cool-beans /home/usr/test2/ \
    /home/usr/test1/pineapple /home/usr/test2/ \
    /home/usr/test1/pizza /home/usr/test2/ \
    /home/usr/test1/dragons /home/usr/test2/elephant/
```

I get an error. Instead of putting only the folder 'dragons' inside 'elephant' as desired, it puts all of 'cool-beans', 'pineapple', 'pizza' and 'dragons' inside 'elephant', which is not desired. How can I write it in a simplified fashion (without the first example's repetition) whilst achieving the same output? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple destinations in a single `rsync` command. What happened when you tried the "simplified" version is that all paths except for the last were treated as sources from which to copy data, so your copied not only from `cool-beans`, `pineapple`, `pizza` and `dragons` but also from `test2` itself (repeatedly). The `--dry-run` option is really useful when trying something out for the first time.

Your set can be simplified into two calls. Either in full:

```bash
rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress /home/usr/test1/cool-beans /home/usr/test1/pineapple /home/usr/test1/pizza /home/usr/test2/
rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress /home/usr/test1/dragons /home/usr/test2/elephant/
```

or using a function to encapsulate the common elements:

```bash
myRsync1() {
    rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress "$@"
}

myRsync1 /home/usr/test1/cool-beans /home/usr/test1/pineapple /home/usr/test1/pizza /home/usr/test2/
myRsync1 /home/usr/test1/dragons /home/usr/test2/elephant/
```

If you can guarantee that most paths begin with a fixed component you could further simplify the visible use of the function call by providing a common path - which must already exist - as the first argument:

```bash
myRsync2() (
    cd -- "$1" || return 1
    shift
    rsync --delete-after -uavh --progress "$@"
)
```

and then calling:

```bash
myRsync2 /home/usr/test1 cool-beans pineapple pizza /home/usr/test2/
myRsync2 /home/usr/test1/dragons /home/usr/test2/elephant
```

or:

```bash
myRsync2 /home/usr test1/cool-beans test1/pineapple test1/pizza test2/
myRsync2 /home/usr test1/dragons test2/elephant
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `rsync` can accept multiple sources, but only one destination. rsync has to be called several times.

You could, however, put the identical rsync and options-part into a variable and call that instead:

```
rsync_call="rsync --delete-after -uvah --progress"
$rsync_call /source/one/ /destination/one/
$rsync_call /source/two/ /destination/two/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't work, but was close. I will mark it as answer if you change it to this, which does work:
`rsync_call="rsync --delete-after -uvah --progress"
$rsync_call /source/one /destination/one/`

Comment: rathier and @ItHertz - please don't put code into variables. Use variables for data and functions for code

Comment: I'm a novice and don't know best coding practice here, so will take your word for it that functions are best for code and have accepted that answer instead.Both answers achieved the desired outcome.